# CDF and PDF of transformed variables from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A random variable U follows the uniform distribution of (-1,1). Find the cumulative distribution functions and density for the transformed variables listed below.

a. $X = |U|$

b. $Y = -ln(|U|)$

c. $W = (1 - |U|)^3$

d. $T = (1 - |U|)^{1/2}$

I have a test tomorrow and really would like to understand the practice exam question.

Comment: You should tell us what attempts you have made.

Comment: Well my main problem is what do I put in place of $U$? If I know what $U$ is I can just plug it in and manipulate the equation.

Comment: (a) should be obvious and may make the others slightly easier.  The density of $U$ is $\frac12$ and the cumulative distribution function is $\frac12 (u+1)$ for $u \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: I understand that the cdf is $P (X<=x) = piecewise | (x-min)/(max-min) | min<=x<=max
1 | x>max$ and the PDF is $piecewise | 1/(max-min) | min<=x<=max
0 | (otherwise)$, how do I use this when transforming U? I have looked at graphs of it for example like $-ln(|U|)$ I see that the graph looks like this (-1,0)U(0,1)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: It helps a lot if you draw pictures of the functions you're trying to map to, so you know which probabilities map to which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to figure out $F_X(x)$, the CDF of $X$ (similarly for $Y$, etc.)
**for all real numbers** $x$.  One simple calculation is to find the
maximum possible value $x_{\max}$ of $X$ and the minimum possible
value $x_{\min}$ of $X$ and set $F_X(x) = 1$ for all $x \geq x_{\max}$
and $F_x(x) = 0$ for all $x < x_{\min}$.

Next, choose your favorite real number $x \in (x_{\min}, x_{\max})$ and 
write
$$F_X(x) = P\{X\leq x\} = P\{U \in A\}$$ where
$A$ is a set of real numbers that you need to figure out all by yourself.
Remember that $A$ has the property that $X \leq x$ exactly when $U \in A$,
and of course, $A$ will depend on the choice of $x$.
Now, compute $P\{U \in A\}$ using the known pdf of $U$ and your knowledge
of the set $A$. Integration might be required for this.

Repeat for your next favorite real number, and then the next most
favorite, and so on.  After a while, you might have an "Aha!" moment
where you realize that for *all* real numbers $x$ in some interval
$(\alpha, \beta)$, you will find that $F_X(x) = \gamma(x)$ for some function
$\gamma(\cdot)$.  Now pick a number in $(x_{\min}, x_{\max}) - (\alpha,\beta)$
and keep going.  You will thus come up with a complete description of
the function $F_X(x)$.  **Warning:** It is only in very rare cases that
$F_X(x)$ can be expressed by a single "formula" valid for all $x$.

Now, differentiate $F_X(x)$ to find the density $f_X(x)$.

Repeat all this for the other variables.

Trust me: it gets easier with practice. But you got to do it yourself,
and struggle with finding sets $A$ and checking to make sure you have
accounted for all $x$, etc; just blindly copying down what your instructor or
TA writes on the blackboard or the leader of your "study group" writes
on his homework solutions will *not* work.  Learning probability theory (indeed,
learning any branch of mathematics) is *not* a spectator sport; you have to
struggle with it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The CDF of X is given by: F(x) = P{X< x} = P{|U|< x} = P{-x< U< x}. Now its simply a matter of integrating from -x to x, where the integrand is the pdf of U, which is 1\2. This should give you F(x)=x. To get the pdf of X, you differentiate F(x) to obtain 1. Also note that X is defined on (0,1). You can follow this method for the rest of the problems. Just be careful with the negatives and square roots.